# MasterMind Game - How to make buttons change into different backcolors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

l have a few difficulties

**First Thing** is that I'm trying to make my OvalShapes generate a different Color, each time i'm pressing on the START button, like in a lottery. I will Change the OvalShapes into Buttons because its easier. They are supposed to turn into one out of 6 available Colors.

**Second thing** is about  my "Feedback/Answer Buttons" in my Master Mind game (the ones in the **red box**) I named them *btnAnswer1_1* .. *btnAnswer1_2* and so on.... Each Row has 4 smaller Buttons that are supposed to Show whether the BackColors in the bigger Buttons on the left( i named them *btnChange1_1 btnChange1_2* and so on..), are correct. If the Color is correct but its in a **WRONG** place, one of the smaller Buttons should turn red. If the Color is correct and its in the **RIGHT** place, one button should turn Black. If you get 4 Black boxes = you win the game.

I'm sure that a lot of you guys, played this game before and that you know the rules. Hopefully some of you created a game like this in C# and you could give me some tips.

I'm writing the whole Thing in c#, unfortunately it's my first contact with this language and that's why I'm having difficulties. I'm supposed to be finished today. Thanks for help!

[image]

Here is an example of my Color button from the first row and the Answer button.

```
private void btnChange1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);

    switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
    {
        case "Red":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        case "Black":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        case "Green":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case "Yellow":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Purple;
            break;
        case "Purple":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            break;
        case "Blue":
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            break;
        default:
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
    }
}

private void btnAnswer1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```